# Tradução para a palavra em ingles "interestingness"

Tags: uso-de-palavras, tradução-inglês, palavra-para-ideia, vocabulário

É comum encontrar o termo "interestingness" quando se quer dizer que algo desperta interesse ou é por si interessante. Por exemplo, a frase:

*These are used to produce a large set of candidate stories which
are subsequently ranked based on their interestingness and coherence.*

Que palavra, simples ou composta, poderíamos utilizar para manter esta representação, e esta construção frásica, sem necessariamente utilizarmos uma frase como:

*"pela sua característica em despertar interesse ou ser interessante"*

Que resultaria em algo como:

[...] *"que são posteriormente ordenadas baseando-se na sua coerência e na **capacidade de despertar interesse**"*

Comment: interestingness is not very usual in English. That said, ness is condition or state. Acho que a sua tradução é boa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que a possibilidade mais simples é "[interesse](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/interesse)":

> 6. qualidade do que retém a atenção ou desperta a curiosidade; importância; utilidade

Mas penso que a frase mencionada na pergunta ("capacidade de despertar interesse") é uma opção mais clara, e pode ser preferível.